# Create styled image programmatically

Tags: 8, media

I have a module that create custom PDF with multiple selected nodes and I use the below function to create the link to styled images:

```
$file = File::load($img_id);
$imagesPath[] = ImageStyle::load('550x300')->buildUrl($file->uri->value);
```

Unfortunately, the image itself is not created, only the link, which is ok if I display it on a simple webpage because Drupal will create it on the fly when needed but on a PDF it cause errors because the image it not found before the PDF could be displayed.

Is there a programmatically way to create this image ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to execute [`createDerivative()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Entity%21ImageStyle.php/function/ImageStyle%3A%3AcreateDerivative/8.6.x) on `ImageStyle`.

```
$image_style = ImageStyle::load('550x300');

$file = File::load($img_id);
$image_uri = $file->getFileUri();
$destination_uri = $image_style->buildUri($file->uri->value);
$image_style->createDerivative($image_uri, $destination_uri);
```

For Drupal 7 there is [`image_style_create_derivative()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_style_create_derivative/7.x):

```
$style = image_style_load('550x300');

$file = file_load($img_id);
$image_uri = $file->uri;
$destination = image_style_path($style['name'], $image_uri);
image_style_create_derivative($style, $image_uri, $destination);
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with [Image Style Warmer](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_style_warmer) module which is available for D8. Worked perfectly for me! This might help other people, who are trying to find a solution.

> The Image Style Warmer module provides options to create image styles
>   during upload or via queue worker. So configured image derivates
>   already exists when they are requested.
>
> - Pre-generate configured image styles on image upload or crop change.
> - Pre-generate configured image styles via queue worker.