# How can I get image style URL based on the file stored in the module?

Tags: 10

Given `mymodule` with image `img/1.png`.

I'm trying to get the image style of that image programmatically.

```php
$module_path = \Drupal::service('module_handler')->getModule('mymodule')->getpath();
$url = ImageStyle::load('image_style_id')->buildUrl($module_path . '/img/1.png');
```

In that case `$url` contains a URL but the image is not generated and not available.
How to build an image style URL in that case properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create styled image programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273817/create-styled-image-programmatically)

Comment: AFAIK image styles can only be used with managed files (those with an ID and file path in the database), you can not generate image styles on the fly from random arbitrary files in your theme or module. I think you need to create and store a File entity first (the path can point to the module dir, but the DB entry must exist)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Although image styles cannot be used here, it is probably possible to use the lower level image to apply an image effect plugin using an image toolkit plugin on a given path. This would end up with an unmanaged file saved at a destination, which could potentially be deleted by file cleanup routines.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

1. Load the image file as an ImageInterface instance using `image.factory` service.
2. Load the image style entity.
3. Traverse the effects of the image style and apply each effect to the ImageInterface instance.
4. Save the ImageInterface instance to an available file system scheme

Example:

```
$module_path = \Drupal::service('module_handler')->getModule('mymodule')->getpath();
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Image\ImageInterface $image */
$image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($module_path . '/img/1.jpg');
$image_style = ImageStyle::load('image_style_id');
/** @var \Drupal\image\ImageEffectInterface $effect */
foreach ($image_style->getEffects() as $effect) {
   $effect->apply($image);
}
// This should be a valid stream wrapper destination rather than the module directory.
// That could cause it to get deleted later automatically.
$success = $image->save('public://my_module/images/1.image_style_id.jpg');
```